# ReportViewer deletando dados do banco Access

Tags: c#, microsoft-access, reportviewer, oledb

Recentemente adicionei o ReportViewer ao meu Visual Studio 2015 Community para criação e impressão de relatórios. Meu banco de dados já continha informações, adicionadas antes de adicionar o ReportViewer.

Tenho atualmente 4 *reports*.

Após eu fazer todas as ligações do banco com os relatórios, para puxarem os dados necessário da tabela a cada impressão, comecei a ter problemas. Ao adicionar algum dado, ele fica salvo até eu usá-lo, em algum momento, para imprimir um relatório, sejam dados de um Tablix, ou uma caixa de texto que contém apenas uma linha do banco.

Aliás, ao editar o banco no diretório, ele simplesmente deleta tudo que foi inserido ao iniciar o programa, ou seja, os únicos dados que ficam são aqueles que estavam registrados antes de ligar o banco aos relatórios.

Gostaria de saber se essa é a forma correta de criar relatórios que tenham relação com o banco, caso seja gostaria de uma solução. Utilizo parâmetros no relatório, a não ser pelos dados do Tablix.

Qualquer outra informação necessária será fornecida.
Grato.

**EDIT**

Consegui uma solução: no *Solution Explorer* fui até o arquivo do meu banco de dados, abri suas propriedades e a propriedade *Copy to output directory* coloquei *Do not copy*, e pronto! O que estava acontecendo era que toda vez que o banco dentro do programa era chamado pelo *ReportViewer*, ele pegava uma cópia já salva e reescrevia sobre o arquivo no diretório, ou seja, um backup era salvo em cima do qual estava sendo usado no sistema todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui uma solução: no *Solution Explorer* fui até o arquivo do meu banco de dados, abri suas propriedades e a propriedade *Copy to output directory* coloquei *Do not copy*, e pronto! O que estava acontecendo era que toda vez que o banco dentro do programa era chamado pelo ReportViewer, ele pegava uma cópia já salva e reescrevia sobre o arquivo no diretório, ou seja, um backup era salvo em cima do qual estava sendo usado no sistema todo.